# Site Not IE 8 Compatible -- Quick Fix?

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer-8, compatibility

I've been tasked with debugging and bringing a website into compatibility with IE 8, which I'm surprised to see still dominates the market share of IE users.  The site uses HTML, CSS and jQuery with the jQuery UI. There are some HTML5 specific tags and CSS3 selectors in the build. It looks and works well in IE 9 and 10 (at least as far as my IE compatibility settings provide the view for IE 9) as well as the latest Firefox and Chrome, but it's completely "hosed" in IE 8.

The site is visible here:
http://www.newschoolaikido.com

It's a total mess in IE 8 and to be perfectly honest I'm not even sure where to begin -- and for someone who has traditionally specialized in tough x-browser compatibility issues that's saying a lot.  I will be searching StackOverflow for any helpful advice today on similar issues; meanwhile, if someone could eyeball this in IE 8 and give me any pointers it would be appreciated. Am I going to need a completely different build and a sniffer for this?  Also, is there something quick I could do in the meantime while working on it to indicate to users they might want to switch to 9 or 10, or use FF or Chrome, to view the site?

Any advice would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: Figure out where the weak points are and code around them. For example, look for floated elements that have a margin/padding in the same direction as the float, rounded corners, opacity, HTML5 elements such as <aside> and <nav>, etc. If you see heavy usage of !important, it may be time to refactor it completely. Generally posting a link to your site and asking what is wrong with it is frowned upon on SO.

Comment: a "*quick fix*" would be to use the chromeframe plugin, however that only works if people actually download it (if they're too lazy to upgrade to IE9, what makes you think they'll download a plugin they've never heard of?)

Comment: Run your code through [the w3c validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.newschoolaikido.com%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0) and fix the errors it raises.

Comment: Thanks for the SO etiquette advice, Kevin, I appreciate it. I come here all the time looking for tips and solutions (this place is a goldmine) but I think this is the first time I've posted a question.  I will keep what you said in mind for the future.

Comment: I'm voting this comment (about remembering to validate) up as well because this, too, is important to include in the process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest implemeting the Modernizr Javascript library. It optimizes the latest HTML and CSS standards for IE. It should help a great deal, but you might still have to fix certain CSS-rules.

http://modernizr.com/

Comment: Thank you for this. I had forgotten about Modernizr until you mentioned it -- I'll give that a shot and report back my results!

Comment: Thanks so much for reminding me about this great tool. I plugged it in and it instantly removed 99% of the issues.  There's only one issue left to fix now, an embedded WuFoo form.  And of course I have to scale down my Modernizr build to just the components needed to reduce load time, and then push it all live.  But this has saved me an incredible amount of time and lifted a weight from my shoulders too.  Thank you Jens!